# Angular update from 10 to 11 is giving error

Tags: angular, version, upgrade

Actual project is of version 9. upgrade from version 9 to 10 is done successfully. when I checked the angular version `ng v` it is showing version 10 and package file is also updated with version 10. but while upgrading from 10 to 11 is giving me below error.

Running the below command to upgrade from version 10

**`ng update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11 --force`**

getting the below error

```
The installed Angular CLI version is outdated.
Installing a temporary Angular CLI versioned 11.2.19 to perform the update.
✔ Package successfully installed.
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 31 dependencies.
Fetching dependency metadata from registry...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular-devkit/build-angular @ "0.1102.19" (was "0.1002.4")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/cli @ "11.2.19" (was "10.2.4")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/compiler-cli @ "11.2.14" (was "10.2.5")...
    Updating package.json with dependency karma @ "6.4.0" (was "5.0.9")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/animations @ "11.2.14" (was "10.2.5")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/common @ "11.2.14" (was "10.2.5")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/compiler @ "11.2.14" (was "10.2.5")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/core @ "11.2.14" (was "10.2.5")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/forms @ "11.2.14" (was "10.2.5")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/localize @ "11.2.14" (was "10.2.5")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/platform-browser @ "11.2.14" (was "10.2.5")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/platform-browser-dynamic @ "11.2.14" (was "10.2.5")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/router @ "11.2.14" (was "10.2.5")...
  UPDATE package.json (1331 bytes)
⠹ Installing packages (npm)...npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: *****@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1002.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1102.19" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1102.19" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@11.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^11.0.0 || ^11.2.0-next" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1102.19
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1102.19" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See /Users/****/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/*****/.npm/_logs/2022-06-28T06_25_22_421Z-debug-0.log
✖ Package install failed, see above.
✖ Migration failed. See above for further details.
```

ps: **** are some names related to folder name and project name

Answer (score 0):

Follow what it says; you're already using `--force`, but you'll find there are plenty of packages out there that force you in to needing the `--legacy-peer-deps` flag as well.

Run it with both.

I've upgraded several projects and now pretty much all of them need the legacy flag because so many deps just aren't updated.